# Mechanical Wave propagation in fluids

Tags: waves

My book says that since a transverse wave in strings involves shearing/tangential stress, the same cannot propagate in fluids as they yield to shearing stress. Hence the propagation of waves wherein bulk modulus is involved (longitudinal) only takes place in fluids. But then it says that waves produced by a sailing motorboat are both longitudinal and transverse. Why?

Comment: As far a I know: transverse wave in linear strings are not due to shear stress but to normal stress; i.e. tension. Both transverse and longitudinal waves are present in fluids, a transverse wave in fluids do not necessarily implies the presence of shear stresses.

Comment: Surface waves can be transversal.

Comment: Oh okay, my book might be talking about the surface waves which show transverse nature. Cool.

Comment: Also I don’t think there is any normal stress in string waves/transverse waves as the tension is along the string and hence along the direction of wave propagation ,ripping and pulling onto the parts of string(which constitute the waveform).

Comment: There is no shear stress in an idealized stretched string under tension, but the transverse vibrations of a beam (with no end load applied) do depend on the existence of shear stress. For a stretched metal *wire* as compared with an idealized string, the shear stress *does* have an effect which causes the vibration frequencies to be slightly different from the simple 1:2:3:4:... frequency ratio. This is a measurable effect in musical instruments like guitar and piano. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inharmonicity.

Comment: @alephzero this is true for Timoshenko beam theory; However, the more common Bernoulli-Euler beam theory do not allows shear stresses.